# Magento Marketplace extention does not install properly

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, magento-connect-manager, marketplace

We have download the custom extension and install via shop back **Magento Connect Manager**. And upload the extension via **Direct package file upload**.

But throw below mention error:

> CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
>
> Invalid package name, allowed: [a-zA-Z0-9_-] chars

So we have find the extension `package.xml` file

```
<name>packagename+Package_Name</name>
```

[image: Error via install extension by shop backend]

How to solve this Issue!!.

Comment: What is the package name?

Comment: Royal Mail Shipping.

Comment: Yeah that is the extension name but what is the package name? Like RoyalMail_Shipping-0.1.0 ?

Comment: The compressed package i have downloaded from the marketplace has the name 'meanbee-Meanbee_Royalmail-2.7.7'. While i read the package.xml file and could the find name tag as

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <package>
        <name>meanbee+Meanbee_Royalmail</name>

I could sense the name has been derived from the URL (https://marketplace.magento.com/meanbee-meanbee-royalmail.html). Is this an issue in uploading or someother thing ? To your notice i have also downloaded the 'dotmailer-dotmailermagento-6.1.0' from marketplace which stands the same thing as the other extension

Comment: @Sankar_k okay, dont you want to try to install through FTP.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento Yeah i can install through FTP, but the issue is why can't i couldn't able to install the extension as expected. ?? I personally have the problems with some randomly downloaded extensions. Is this a problem with newly integrated Marketplace ??

Comment: @Sankar_k i have no idea about that, sorry for that.... you have solution of `ftp`,  but it's good that you are trying to find a reason for that, good luck.....

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, the name of the package in `package.xml` is `meanbee+Meanbee_Royalmail`

However, as you can see from the error, **`+` is not an allowed character in package names.** So you should contact Meanbee directly, so they can repackage their module and fix that.

Alternatively, you could try changing `meanbee+Meanbee_Royalmail` to `meanbee-Meanbee_Royalmail` and try to use that package instead.

Also, as Baby in Magento suggested, FTP is another alternative

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....

Comment: Yeah i will take down the things about the security concern. But Magento system have migrated the extensions from Magento connect to Magento Marketplace. The issue i have addressed is for the extensions downloaded from Marketplace. (https://marketplace.magento.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As far i have noticed, the question raised is somewhat the issue happened to me as well. I am surfing the Marketplace for quite days now and Magento as said have migrated the extensions from Magento connect as well.

I have extensions downloaded `hiconversion-Hic_Integration-1.1.8`and `instantsearch-autocompleteplus_autosuggest-3.0.12` which falls under the same category. FTP uploading is only option as mentioned.

But i feels the while migrating Magento might have misread the URL or required something from the extension providers which have lead to this issue. Magento 2 installs using composer which have the 'vendor/package' name combination to install. Whereas the Magento 1 extension do not have it, while migrating the Magento might have forced the extension / converted the extension to be written with 'Vendor/package name' which might have lead this issue.

Magento marketplace is still in early stages of integration, **so it's a question whether the Marketplace migration has the fault since almost every extension migrated from Magento connect have the problem**.